# Using each_with_index with map

Tags: ruby

I want to take a array and make it an order list. Currently I'm trying to do it in this way:

```
r = ["a", "b","c"]
r.each_with_index { |w, index| puts "#{index+1}. #{w}" }.map.to_a
# 1. a
# 2. b
# 3. c
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

the output should be `["1. a", "2. b", "3. c"]`.

How do I get the proper output to be the new value for the `r` array?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
a.to_enum.with_index(1).map { |element, index| "#{index}. #{element}" }
```

or

```
a.map.with_index(1) { |element, index| "#{index}. #{element}" }
```

`with_index(1)` makes the index of the first element `1`.

In the first solution the array is converted to an enum, and in the second solution the array is directly mapped.

Comment: The first line worked. Looks like i had to convert the array to enum and back to array again. I'll keep in mind for next time.

Answer (score 11):

```
> => r.each_with_index.map { |w, index| "#{index+1}. #{w}" }

> => ["1. a", "2. b", "3. c"]
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to map *first*, then `puts`:

```
r = %w[a b c]
r.map.with_index do |w, index|
  "#{index + 1}. #{w}"
end.each do |str|
  puts str
end
#=> ["1. a", "2. b", "3. c"]
# prints:
# 1. a
# 2. b
# 3. c
```

This is because `each` (and `each_with_index`) simply returns the original array.

Comment: Or simply `puts` the array resulting from the `map`, which will automatically print each value on its own line. `puts(r.map.with_index{ |w,i| "#{i+1}. #{w}" })`