# Can't see why I have "no implicit conversion from nil to integer" error

Tags: ruby

Hey guys I'm having an issue with this problem. I'm doing exercises from a book and this is one of them.

A collection of spelling blocks has two letters per block, as shown in this list:

```
B:O   X:K   D:Q   C:P   N:A
G:T   R:E   F:S   J:W   H:U
V:I   L:Y   Z:M
```

This limits the words you can spell with the blocks to just those words that do not use both letters from any given block. Each block can only be used once.

Write a method that returns true if the word passed in as an argument can be spelled from this set of blocks, false otherwise.

Examples:

```
block_word?('BATCH') == true
block_word?('BUTCH') == false
block_word?('jest') == true
```

This is my attempt at a solution. I'm reading in the collection from a text document.

```
  text = []
    File.open('example2.txt').each { |line| text << line }
    @pair1 = []
    @pair2 = []
    text.join('').split('   ').each {|x, i| @pair1 << x[0].to_s; @pair2 << x[2].to_s}

    def block_word?(word)
      word = word.upcase
      @pair1.map {|x, i| word.include?(x) && word.include?(@pair2[i]) }.include?(true)
    end

    block_word?('BATCH') == true
    block_word?('BUTCH') == false
    block_word?('jest') == true
```

I'm getting this error. Not sure why.

```
rb2.rb:10:in `[]': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
        from rb2.rb:10:in `block in block_word?'
        from rb2.rb:10:in `map'
        from rb2.rb:10:in `block_word?'
        from rb2.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index `i` is nil, as you are only doing [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map) which iterates over the element only, to use `map` with `index` you need to use `.map.with_index` as shown in the docs which will give you both element `x` and index `i`

```
def block_word?(word)
  word = word.upcase
  @pair1.map.with_index { |x, i| word.include?(x) && word.include?(@pair2[i]) }.include?(true)
end
```

Comment: if you're gonna post links to docs, post links to current version, not one from 6 years ago :)

Comment: Instead of `each_with_index.map`, one can do `map.with_index`.

Comment: yes..thanks...I didn't notice that..I will update. :)

Answer (score 0):

This error raised, because you've trying to access array `@pair2` with `nil` index. `map` method doesn't send index as second argument to provided block. To add them you can add `each_with_index` method before `map`. Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040757/using-each-with-index-with-map).

```
@pair1.each_with_index
   .map{ |x, i| word.include?(x) && word.include?(@pair2[i]) }
   .include?(true)
```

Try this code, it will help to understand what's happen:

```
pair2 = []
puts pair2[nil] # will raise the same exception
```

Comment: Instead of `each_with_index.map`, one can do `map.with_index`.